# Turkey Daylight Saving Time Change (UTC+02:00) Istanbul

Tags: timezone, save, utc, dst, istanbul

Turkey Goverment announced on september 29th, 2015 that Turkey will enter DST on March 29th,2015 till November 8th, 2015

But it seems wrong time zone (UTC+02:00)Istanbul

> Year 2015
>
> DST start March 29th, 2015 at 2:00AM
> DST end  October 25th, 2015 at 3:00AM

when microsoft will release hotfix ?

Comment: You can watch the [Microsoft DST & TZ Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dst2007/) for an announcement, but this is clearly off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hotfix has been announced.  Please see [the Microsoft DST & TZ Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dst2007/archive/2015/10/09/upcoming-windows-dst-update-for-turkey-democratic-people-39-s-republic-of-korea-and-fiji.aspx) for details.